# Only one .idx and .pack files using git gc

Tags: git

Jenkins jobs are running every 5 min. and each forced push creates .idx and .pack files
as you can see at the below;

```
pack-8eca24ab5048f727d323cd7f9fc8ed323f384c40.idx
pack-8eca24ab5048f727d323cd7f9fc8ed323f384c40.pack
.
.
.
```

In consequence these files are huge and I used the command;

```
git gc --aggressive
```

This is worked for me but its manual. The point is; I want to automatically do that.

```
git gc --aggressive --auto
```

This command doesn't work, I just need one .idx and .pack files in my all .git project.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Stop force pushing if you don't know why you're doing it.

Comment: I know why I am using it, I just didn't explain it here. I should overwrite all the time when I push

Comment: Why _are_ you force pushing?

Comment: Needing to force push has a bad smell to me.  It implies that someone or something is overwriting your history.  Fix that first.

Comment: All the time I am pushing TFS project to Git. When I use just git push there are always some conflicts

Comment: This is sounding worse and worse...what are these conflicts?

Comment: I delete Jenkins workspace, because of that .git folder also gone. So git warns fetch/pull first before push. I cannot tell you whyI am doing this while typing. Really trust me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's clear that you think you have a good use case for this, I very much doubt it.  That said, unlike others who've tried to point this out in comments, I don't need to agree with you to answer a simple technical question.

I'm not sure what you expected `--auto` to do.  This is a flag used *when `gc` is run automatically*; it is used by `gc` to know the difference between when *you* tell `gc` to run, vs. when other git commands tell `gc` to run.

If you want to persistently change how the automatic `gc` runs work, then you need to alter the configuration.

You may find the `gc.autoPackLimit` value to be particularly useful here.  By default it lets the pack count reach 50, but if you literally will only tolerate one then you could say

```
git config gc.autoPackLimit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for detail answer @Mark. Should I use this with --auto command ? I tried "git config gc.autoPackLimit 1" and it didn't work.

Comment: Again, the `--auto` flag (it is not a command) is used to note that a particular run is automatic. It is not something you should need to specify in a manually-run command. If you need more information about the controls you can use to affect when auto-gc runs occur or what they do, or to affect what manual gc runs do, you should consult the `git config` documentation.  If you want to trigger a manual gc after every push, you could look at the `git hook` documentation (pre-receive)